# Unselecting and Selecting jQuery radio buttons on change

Tags: jquery, html

I have a page that I have a bunch of radio buttons and kicking on those radio buttons causes an the nearest text input to turn  into a file input, in case they have images they wish to upload.

My issue comes is if they decide that they do not want to have an image I want them to be  able to unselect that radio button and do some functionality to change that file back to a text input.

My html looks like this except I have way more `<tr>` then this. I just didn't want to dump a bunch of code here.

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="1">
      <td>Correction 1</td>
      <td><input type="number" name="page1"  class="form-control" min="1" max="10000"></td>
      <td><input type="number" name="pargraph1"  class="form-control" min="1" max="100000"></td>
      <td><input type="number" name="line1"  class="form-control" min="1" max="100000"></td>
      <td><p><input type="radio" name="add_image1" class="imageInput" value="" /> Adding</p>
        <p><input type="radio" name="add_image1" class="imageInput" value="" /> Replacing</p>
      </td>
      <td class="hidden-480"><input type="text" name="incorrect1" value="" class="form-control" /></td>
      <td class="hidden-480 correct"><input type="text" name="correct1" value="" class="form-control" /></td>
      <td><input class="btn-small btn btn-success" type="submit" name="" value="Done" /></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

and my query looks like this at the moment.

```
$('.correctionList').on('change', '.imageInput', function() {

   if($('.imageInput').is(':checked')) { 
        $(this).closest($('tr')).find('.correct').html('<input type="file" name="correct'+num+'" value="" class="form-control" /></td>');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        $(this).prop('checked', true);
    }

    if($('.imageInput').hasClass('selected') && $('.imageInput').is(':checked')){
                    $(this).closest($('tr')).find('.correct').html('<input type="text" name="correct'+num+'" value="" class="form-control" /></td>');
        $(this).removeClass('selected');
        $(this).prop('checked', false);
    }
});
```

and I know I am on the right track here, but maybe I'm not calling the right thing to deselect the radio buttons. Any help would be awesome.

Here is a jsFiddle to kind of show what is happening. http://jsfiddle.net/pPE9W/

Comment: @NickR You can deselect a radio button with this code $(this).prop('checked', false); I'm having an issue with how I'm calling it to make it work. I cannot use a checkbox because I don't want them to be able to select both, it has to be either or

Comment: I agree with @NickR in that it still isn't very intuitive for a user to deselect a radio button. It would probably be better to have checkboxes and just use some script to deselect the other if one is selected.

Comment: @Goose I cannot use checkboxes for the reason I stated above as well as other reasons inside my application. And the way my interface is layer out, which you are not seeing, is actually very intuitive.

Comment: Having a radio button automatically deselect on click is confusing. I think you need to add a third radio button for 'text' or whatever. [Add image] [Replace image] [Make corrections]

Comment: @isherwood I cannot do that because it would force the user to select that if they have text and that is not optional. In my interface it is very clear what is happening. I just want to give them an option to unselect if they accidentally click on the radio button. That is all I really want to do.

Comment: You can still load your text inputs by default. The [Make corrections] option would simply restore them if they'd been changed. Call it [Reset] if you prefer.

Comment: @isherwood I would rather not have to do that. I would just like to have the option to deselect them. Adding another field would make this more confusing and difficult to use. I know this is possible, I have seen this happen in other applications, I just cannot get this to work in my situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a little ugly, but it works:

```
$(document).on('mousedown', 'input[type=radio]:checked', function() {
    var that = $(this);
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(that).prop('checked', false);
    }, 150);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/pPE9W/1/

Comment: As long as it works it can be a little ugly. haha Thank you very, very much!!